# How do I pass a variable to the then callback of an asynchronous function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Below I have some example code that depicts a different task that I am trying to accomplish.

In the example code, I have a helper function named `outer_func(multiplier)` that I will call from a different module.  This helper function receives a single parameter, `multiplier`.

However before I use this parameter, I need to asynchronously obtain the array of data points.  This function does not require the use of multiplier and I cannot call the subsequent functions until I have received the array.  So I would like to know how I can best pass the multiplier to the function nested within the `.then` callback of `get_array()`.

```
var fn2 = function asyncMultiplyBy2(v){ // sample async action
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(v * 2), 100));
}

var fn3 = function asyncMultiplyBy3(v, w /*I want to pass multiplier here*/){ // sample async action
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(v * w), 100));
}

function get_array() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 100));
}

function outer_func(multiplier) {
  get_array().then(function(array) {
    var actions = array.map(fn2);
    var results = Promise.all(actions);

    results.then(function(newArray) {
      var finalActions = newArray.map(fn3);
      var finalResults = Promise.all(finalActions);
      console.log(multiplier)  //undefined, but I would like to use this variable here

      finalResults.then(function(finalArray) {
        console.log(finalArray);
      })
    })
  })
}

outer_func(3);
```

EDIT:
I added a comment to `fn3` for where I would like to pass multiplier.

Comment: have you checked that multiplier is defined in the first place? The scoping looks fine and I would expect multiplier to be available where you need it. Pasting the above code into jsfiddle works as I think you expect it to. multiplier logs as 3

Comment: If you passed multiplier then it would work, it will also be undefined at the beginning of your func so not sure what you're asking?

Comment: he is talking about nodejs behaviour is different

Comment: @ShyamJoshi No, nodejs scoping rules and closure behaviour are not different. The posted code works.

Comment: @Bergi I believe you are correct, not sure why I was getting undefined at the output but I am seeing 3 now.  I'll close this and add a new question for the second portion of this question.   Thanks.